# Magento 2 admin grid first row empty issue

Tags: magento2, export, custom-admin-grid

I have custom module and implemented custom grid. Everything working fine as expected. only issue with while export data, i am getting first row as empty. From second row on words showing  column header and from third row on words showing table data. All table records are showing in grid and csv file. There is no data miss. Only issue with export csv file first row have empty. I am using UI component for admin grid implementation and using export tags for export i.e.

Comment: Hi @RakeshDonga Thank you for your reply. I didn't written any extra code for export functionality, just i added export button in ui component file as per magento ui compoent standards.

Comment: this code is working for you?

Comment: @RakeshDonga I just implemented like that code, lastly I received a solution. I have a dropdown ui componet field let's say like months[dropdown]. Following this link[ https:/stackoverflow.com/questions/48836155/magento-2-custom-import-remove-import-behaviour] now export work fine, implies first row not coming empty. Thank you for your precious moment and answers.

Comment: @RakeshDonga sure, you can............

Comment: i have updated my answer check it

Answer (score 2):

> First create your UI Component

```
<listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <exportButton class="Magento\Ui\Component\ExportButton" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/export" displayArea="dataGridActions">
            <settings>
                <options>
                    <option name="cvs" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="value" xsi:type="string">csv</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">CSV</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="string">controller/results/export</item>
                    </option>
                    <option name="xml" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="value" xsi:type="string">xml</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Excel XML</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="string">skininc/results/export</item>
                    </option>
                </options>
            </settings>
        </exportButton>
</listingToolbar>
```

> Next create your controller for skininc/results/export

```
<?php
/**
 * @category Magento 2 Module
 * @package  Overdosedigital\Frontendflow
 * @author   Don Nuwinda
 */
namespace MyModule\Frontendflow\Controller\Adminhtml\Results;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\WriteInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
use Magento\Ui\Model\Export\ConvertToCsv;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory;
use MyModule\Frontendflow\Model\ResourceModel\MyData\CollectionFactory;

class Export extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\ForwardFactory
     */
    protected $resultForwardFactory;

    /**
     * Massactions filter
     *
     * @var Filter
     */
    protected $filter;

    /**
     * @var MetadataProvider
     */
    protected $metadataProvider;
    /**
     * @var WriteInterface
     */
    protected $directory;
    /**
     * @var ConvertToCsv
     */
    protected $converter;
    /**
     * @var FileFactory
     */
    protected $fileFactory;



    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory,
        Filter $filter,
        Filesystem $filesystem,
        ConvertToCsv $converter,
        FileFactory $fileFactory,
        \Magento\Ui\Model\Export\MetadataProvider $metadataProvider,
        \MyModule\Frontendflow\Model\ResourceModel\MyData $resource,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
        ) {
            $this->resources = $resource;
            $this->filter = $filter;
            $this->_connection = $this->resources->getConnection();
            $this->directory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::VAR_DIR);
            $this->metadataProvider = $metadataProvider;
            $this->converter = $converter;
            $this->fileFactory = $fileFactory;
            parent::__construct($context);
            $this->resultForwardFactory = $resultForwardFactory;
            $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * export.
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Forward
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $collection = $this->filter->getCollection($this->collectionFactory->create());

        $component = $this->filter->getComponent();
        $this->filter->prepareComponent($component);
        $dataProvider = $component->getContext()->getDataProvider();
        $dataProvider->setLimit(0, false);
        $ids = [];

        foreach ($collection as $document) {
            $ids[] = (int)$document->getId();
        }

        $searchResult = $component->getContext()->getDataProvider()->getSearchResult();
        $fields = $this->metadataProvider->getFields($component);
        $options = $this->metadataProvider->getOptions();
        $name = md5(microtime());
        $file = 'export/'. $component->getName() . $name . '.csv';
        $this->directory->create('export');
        $stream = $this->directory->openFile($file, 'w+');
        $stream->lock();
        $stream->writeCsv($this->metadataProvider->getHeaders($component));
        foreach ($searchResult->getItems() as $document) {
            if( in_array( $document->getId(), $ids ) ) {
                $this->metadataProvider->convertDate($document, $component->getName());
                $stream->writeCsv($this->metadataProvider->getRowData($document, $fields, $options));
            }
        }
        $stream->unlock();
        $stream->close();
        return $this->fileFactory->create('export.csv', [
            'type' => 'filename',
            'value' => $file,
            'rm' => true  // can delete file after use
        ], 'var');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou, working fine.